# Quartz with centralized scheduling and monitoring

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

We are trying to revamp our batch job scheduling and monitoring process over the entire enterprise. Currently all our batch jobs are scheduled using Unix crontab and are monitored using log files generated by shell scripts.

This process has lot of disadvantages and as the number of applications grow this gets really complicated.

1. Two copies of applications need to be deployed one to App-Server and one as standalone(since business logic is shared between both). This is complicating our build process too.
2. There is no easy of use web-ui for us to see the status of jobs and manually run failed jobs remotely without getting onto the unix box.
3. There is no fail over or load balanced batch processing.

So I was thinking of using Quartz (with our existing Spring apps) in our applications and deploy them to App-Servers and no longer rely on the unix crontab.

Is there a way I can write a centralized web application from where I can schedule and monitor jobs running on different quartz schedulers on different app servers?

P.S: I know quartzdesk.com is one solution, but I don't want to enable RMI on my JVM.

Comment: It might be an overkill, but I would look at Kafka streams... It is basically a publish/subscribe service, but consumers mark items as consumed when done.

Comment: Another alternative is to dockerize your jobs and use something like Chronos for fault tolerance.

Comment: Thank you @MFARID for the suggestions. As per my understanding Kafka is used for real-time processing of data and we don't want to do it because we have a lot of timings issues. Also in regard to dockers, we don't use dockers in our environment and I don't think there are plans to implement in anytime soon.

Comment: Minor correction: QuartzDesk does not use RMI, it uses JMX. Regardless of what GUI and monitoring platform you will use, you may want to look into quartzdesk-executor project on GitHub. It is a Quartz-based app ready to be used as a centralized job scheduling solution capable of running arbitrary executable files located on the localhost as well as remote servers (via SSH). When used with QuartzDesk, it can intercept std/err output produced by executed scripts and show it in the GUI. I am biased here as I am one of the authors.

Comment: Spring cloud data flow can be an option

Answer (score 0):

You could use SpringBoot scheduler as an Orchestrator and call REST APIs for the remote (or local, if you are small) execution. This way, as your app grows you could easily leverage a load balancer.

If you have the possibility of using cloud services (like Amazon, Azure or Google Cloud), this could be done easily using their own load balancers. They also support docker and could take care of any peaks of utilization.